# laravel deployed on google app engine doesn't upload files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel

I am trying to upload a file, I am using laravel 4 and deploy on google app engine. Locally file upload works, but then when deploy with google app engine it doesn't.
Here is my code:

view:

```
{{ Form::model($v, array('files' => true,'route' => array('upload.image', $v->id),'method' => 'post','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'upload-images')) }}
            {{ Form::file('image') }}
            <br>
            {{ Form::submit('Add Photo', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary' )) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

controller

```
$file = Input::file('image');
        dd($file);
        $destinationPath = 'img_gallery/';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = 'img_' . $id . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        $car = Car::find($id);
        $car->Pic = $filename;
        $car->save();
        return Redirect::to('/');
```

and it displays an array with file attr. But when deployed with google app engine this code returns NULL. After readin google app engine documentation for php I understood that the problem is that in google app engine you can't write to filesystem app, and in [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload#createuploadurl_options) I found that code for php without laravel and tried to combine with mine like below:

upload_test.blade.php

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';

use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'images_upload'];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('upload.handler', $options);
?>
<div class="body">
    <form action="<?php echo $upload_url ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
```

controller

```
 public function upload_image($id) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        dd($file);
}
```

route

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::post('upload_handler', array('as' => 'upload.handler', 'uses' => 'CarController@upload_handler'));
});
```

controller

```
public function upload_handler() {
        var_dump($_FILES);
    }
```

But this displays:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Which I know that is an error because form post is not pointing to a route, instead to a variable. The image is stored in google app engine but the problem is that this code doesn't post to controller in order to save path of file in DB. I have tried other ways but no result. I also followed step by step section 6 in [this](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/). Furthermore I tried [Ajessup package](https://packagist.org/packages/ajessup/laravel) but no result.

Comment: You don't appear to be doing things in the MVC way that Laravel 4 is intended to be used - the upload handler should really point to a Controller (http://laravel.com/docs/controllers) via a Route (http://laravel.com/docs/routing), and in the Routes config you can specify which http methods are allowed for the given route. Including the cloud storage lib should also really be handled outside of the view.

Comment: @glendaviesnz I edited my question. take a look

Comment: Doh - sorry - overlooked the implications of running Laravel on app engine in my first comment, which complicates things slightly as far as routing file uploads via the controllers as you would normally do  - hopefully someone else has a solution to this for you - pointing Laravel Storage to Cloud Storage as outlined at https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/ may be an option.

Comment: @glendaviesnz I tried it but still the same. It doesn't pass attr of file upload from view to controller. What other option do I have? Can I upload files in google drive with google app engine?

Comment: @Stuart Langley could you take a look at my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line:

```
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('upload.handler', $options);
```

the first arg should be a URL-- try removing the quotes (assuming that `upload.handler` points to where you want it to), or try replacing that arg with the actual URL that the app should redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a permission problem if it works with your local dev server and not your remote server. To fix it try the following:

1. Go to [cloud console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?utm_referrer=blank)
2. Go to your project, storage, cloud storage, storage browser
3. Check if your bucket exists and if it has permission of write for your service account name that can be found in the [appengine dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/settings)

I recommend that you use the default GCS bucket:

1. Go to [appenigne dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/settings), application settings
2. If you have a button that says something like: generate cloud integration project, click on it
3. If there is a Google Cloud Storage Bucket listed there, use that as an alternative to your "images_upload" bucket. It should be similar to "appid.appspot.com"

Comment: I did what you told me but still displays a NULL insted of file attr that are displayed locally. Any other suggestion?

Comment: where to check for write permissions?

Comment: Select the bucket, bucket permissions, and check if in that list there is the service account name with write.

Comment: I am using the default bucket, and still doesn't upload the file

Comment: In php.ini near the file app.yaml did you add google_app_engine.enable_functions = "libxml_disable_entity_loader"? A friend of mine that used uploading and php had to put that there in order to work

Comment: If I add this line it makes all pages blank

Comment: And no still NULL during upload

Comment: One other thing you might try to do is accept the GET method to your route thing that does the same thing as on POST. Appengine when uploading your files, goes to a handler that uploads the file and saves it to blobstore, then makes a request to your callback link with the file location. (i am not sure if it uses GET or POST when going back to your callback link)

Comment: Now it doesn't shows methodnotallowed exception, it just displays NULL which means post isn't performed. I have all this days that search about this problem and no one had it because there is nothing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative to this scenario is uploading file as a set of chucks of size that the request can handle.

Example project - https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload-example